# Twitter style X minutes ago

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for a PHP date helper function that can compute like Twitter:

```
20 seconds ago
3 minutes ago
1 hour ago
2 hours ago
1 days ago
etc.
```

I'm using a datetime column in the database to store the history.  Should this functionality be done on the database level or on the PHP level?

Comment: Hey, forget Twitter! S.O. does the same but better!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's much better to compute 'X minutes ago' in the browser if you can help it so that you don't miss caching opportunities unnecessarily.

http://timeago.yarp.com/ is a nice jQuery plugin for doing just that.

Comment: Thanks.  Timeago is great.  Front end side time calculation is the way to go.

Comment: LOVE it when StackOverflow gives me a better idea. Was about to do this calc with PHP, but it would have been such a wasted opportunity. Thanks!